# Node.js and MPI (Message Passing Interface)

Tags: node.js, mpi

Are there any javascript libraries for MPI?  I am new to MPI and am learning about intensive parallel processing.  We have a supercomputer at school that we are using that only uses MPI and I was wondering if I could code my programs using Node.js instead of c++.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick search on NPM doesn't reveal anything interesting, so my guess is that it does not exist yet.

However, you can use native libraries with http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html.

You can also use [node-ffi](https://github.com/rbranson/node-ffi/wiki/Node-FFI-Tutorial), which sometimes makes things even simpler.

Answer (score 3):

I know this answer is coming too in April 2019... But for future use and people interested in this topic:

**Option 1**: You can use Node.js **Cluster API** (https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) to mimic or implement simple MPI functions e.g. send, receive, rank, etc.. and much more advanced functions depending on your programming prowess in Node.js.

**Option 2**: You can also use the following Node.js' MPI library, which implements some of MPI functionalities. The library is available in NPM registry:

**mpi-node** - https://www.npmjs.com/package/mpi-node

Comment: **Node.js Cluster API** : Can't use as a cluster of distributed nodes on remote machines.

**mpi-node** : It's only available on LINUX systems.

Answer (score 1):

I recently created [klyng](https://github.com/Mostafa-Samir/klyng), a message-passing distributed computing framework for Node.js influenced by MPI. You can consider it (for now) a small implementation of the MPI Standards in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be one now. It seems to be becoming a popular standard in most languages.

Here's one web site:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/mpi-node